# How do I get the id of each doc when saving an array of documents with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas that look like this:

```
var ToolBoxSchema = new Schema({
   description: String,
   tools: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Tool'}]
});

var Tool = new Schema({
   name: String,
   model: String,
});
```

Let's say I have a new `ToolBox` that has a set of `Tools`. I have an array of `Tools` and would like to use the create method from mongoose to save these tools and then add a reference to the ToolBox.tools array for each tool.

```
var toolBoxModel = mongoose.model('ToolBox', ToolBoxSchema);
var toolModel = mongoose.model('Tool', ToolSchema);

var toolbox = new toolBoxModel();
var tool = new toolModel();
var toolsArray = getTools();
```

Assume getTools() returns an array of tools with X number of elements. 
Ex: [{name: "screwdriver", model: "craftman 3000"}, {name: "drill", model: "black and decker"}]

When I call the model's create method, how can I get a list of all of the documents that were saved?

The example in the mongoose api docs shows each saved document being passed in as a parameter to the callback function, but if the number of elements in the array is different every time then I don't know how to get the id's of all the saved elements in the array.

```
var array = [{ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }];
Candy.create(array, function (err, jellybean, snickers) {
  if (err) // ...
});
```

Is there a way to get back an array of all the saved documents ...maybe something like this:

```
var toolsArray = [{name: "screwdriver", model: "craftman 3000"}, {name: "drill", model: "black and decker"}];
tool.create(toolsArray, function (err, arrayOfToolDocs) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfToolDocs.length; i++) {
        toolbox.tools.push(arrayOfToolDocs[i].id);
    }
    toolbox.save();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get arguments passed into any function by using the arguments object.
For example:

```
function argNum(){
  console.log(arguments.length);
}
argNum('test',1,23,43); // Logs 4
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: So they'll still be passed in even if I don't specify them as parameters?